# How to declare order of column with sqlalchemy.orm?

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have customized a base model `CoModel`, which has declared attributes of `created_time` and `updated_time`.

But How to fixed the order of declared column?

I want `created_time` and `updated_time` to be the last 2 columns while table was created.

```
from datetime import datetime    
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr


session_options = dict(
    bind=None,
    autoflush=False,
    autocommit=False,
    expire_on_commit=False,
)
db = SQLAlchemy(session_options=session_options)


class CoModel():
    """ sample:
    class TableName(db.Model, CoModel):
        pass
    """

    @declared_attr
    def created_time(self):
        return db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    @declared_attr
    def updated_time(self):
        return db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.utcnow)
```

Comment: Why do you want them to be lasts columns declared?

Comment: That would be better and  I  was told the order of table columns can Influence performance .

Comment: While true in some cases, have you verified if it matters for you?

Comment: yes,  I used to manage a huge database (data size > 100G),  and I have to split it to more then 600 tables. 

But in that case,  I didn't try to declared `created_time` and `updated_time` with such `CoModel`. 


Well, in this case,  I just wonder how to fix the order.

Comment: @NicoNing were u able to order the columns